# Remove single quotes export file name in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Using VBScript, I'm getting unintentional single quotes for initPeriod in my export file name with the following

```
initperiod = datepart("YYYY",Date) & strMonth

""Export_File:C:\GrabIt\Test\{Command.idxnum}\{Command.idxnum}_DriverPage_""" & initPeriod & """_YTD.pdf""
```

Result is 11_DriverPage_'201210'_YTD.pdf

How do I remove the single quotes from initPeriod?

Comment: I'm unclear what the second line is doing.  Could you clarify?  For example, what is `Export_File`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want quotes around the entire exportfile line.  In that case, it looks like you are missing a quote at each end.  I'm also guessing that you probably don't want quotes around the value of initPeriod, where you have used too many.  In that case, it should be:

```
"""Export_File:C:\GrabIt\Test\{Command.idxnum}\{Command.idxnum}_DriverPage_" & initPeriod & "_YTD.pdf"""
```

Or if you don't want quotes around the whole thing:

```
"Export_File:C:\GrabIt\Test\{Command.idxnum}\{Command.idxnum}_DriverPage_" & initPeriod & "_YTD.pdf"
```

Keep in mind that "" inside a string means a quote char will be included in the string.  A string set = "" is an empty string.

If that's not it, you'll need to post exactly what outcome you are trying to achieve.